# Mock a method when one of the parameter expected trowing error

Tags: java, junit, mocking

I have a situation where first argument of method `findUser` is something I cant mock `Session.get()`, So it will throw exception but still I want  mock   `findUser`. Any clue guys how to do this. I am using Mockito here.

eg.

```
Emp emp = findUser(Session.get(), "Admin");
```

Note Where Session isn't a static class. It is a static variable of the same class.

Comment: you can't mock Session.get(), but you could wrap it into another function (getSession()), and mock it instead

Comment: you can mock static methods using JMockit. But better solution is as mentioned in above comment, using Mockito

Comment: Can you elaborate and put some sample code in Answer segment.

Comment: You can mock static methods with PowerMockito. Is it what you want to achieve?

Comment: Updated the question :: Note Where Session isn't a static class. It is a static variable of the same class.

Answer (score 0):

There is a library called PowerMockito --> https://www.baeldung.com/intro-to-powermock .  You should be able to mock your Session varg as a mock or spy and handle the return get().  This should then allow you to mock your findUser method passing in the argument types to be expected.  Cheers!